# Get all functions of an object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, enumeration

For example,

```
Math.mymfunc = function (x) {   
    return x+1;
}
```

will be treated as a property and when I write

```
for(var p in Math.__proto__) console.log(p)
```

it will be shown. But the rest of Math functions will not. How can I get all functions of a Math object?

Comment: Just curious, why do you need it?

Comment: `mymfunc` shouldn't appear in the enumeration because you're enumerating a different object (`Math` vs `Object.prototype`). If you're running that code in the console, it may appear as though it does, but really the console is just displaying the result of the assignment.

Comment: One possible use - documentation tool for JS built in objects.  Another use - building a UI to the Math object (a calculator eg)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Math);` is what you are after.

This logs all of the properties provided you are dealing with an EcmaScript 5 compliant browser.

```
var objs = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Math);
for(var i in objs ){
  console.log(objs[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
var functionNames = [];

Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).forEach(function(property) {
  if(typeof obj[property] === 'function') {
    functionNames.push(property);
  }
});

console.log(functionNames);
```

That gives you an array of the names of the properties that are functions. Accepted answer gave you names of all the properties.

Answer (score 2):

[The specification](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-15.8) doesn't appear to define with what properties the `Math` functions are defined with. Most implementations, it seems, apply `DontEnum` to these functions, which mean they won't show up in the object when iterated through with a `for(i in Math)` loop.

May I ask what you need to do this for? There aren't many functions, so it may be best to simply define them yourself in an array:

```
var methods = ['abs', 'max', 'min', ...etc.];
```

Answer (score 0):

`console.log(Math)` should work.

Comment: Except that doesn't give you programmatic access to them, which I imagine is what the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

[Object.getOwnPropertyNames()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames) is a good solution

---

The following example is if you have written a sample script and want to create a button for each function.

```html
<!-- <script src="example.js"></script> -->

<script>
// example.js
function Example_foo() {
  console.log("foo")
}

function Example_bar() {
  console.log("bar")
}

for (const funcName of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this)) {
  if (funcName.startsWith("Example")) {
    const frag = document.createRange().createContextualFragment(`
      <button onclick="${funcName}()">${funcName}</button><br>
    `)
    document.body.append(frag)
  }
}
</script>
```